# sql query to retrieve SESSION value

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have the following code in my axps.cs page ......and m having trouble with fetchin session value in my sql Query:

```
connection.Open();
string sqlStatement = "SELECT date as 'Date',name as 'Name',gender as 'Gender',
                       age as 'Age',addr as 'Address',perAddr as 'Permanent Address',
                       pno as 'Phone No',altName as 'Alternate Contact Person',
                       altPno as 'Alternate Person Pno',fever as 'Duration Of Fever',
                       locType as 'Location Type',patType as 'Patient Type',
                       radTreat as 'Radical Treatment Given?', followup as 'Treatment Status',
                       taluk as 'Taluk',phc as 'PHC',malType as 'Malaria Type',
                       death as 'Death Status' FROM patients 
                       WHERE (**date=Session['selDate'] and name=Session['selName']**)";
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to understand how session items work.
Briefly:

```
string firstName = (string)(Session["First"]);
string lastName = (string)(Session["Last"]);
string city = (string)(Session["City"]);
```

More: do not compose your query manually, use query parameters instead; this will prevent you [Sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) and many headaches due to type conversion (date/time, floating point numbers with different decimal separator and so on).
So you should try

```
string sqlStatement = "SELECT date as 'Date',name as 'Name', ....
                       WHERE date=@pData AND name=@pName";
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pData", (DateTime)Session["selDate"]);
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pName", (String)Session["selName"]);
```